# How to get strftime of yesterday in different lang

Tags: php

i need get the date of yesterday fith strftime ord date function with lang translate.

```
//with strftime but yesterday
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ita', 'it_IT.utf8');
$today = strftime("%d %B %Y");

//with date but without lang
date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
```

Comment: Try to force lang with `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT.UTF-8');`

Comment: i try it, but don't work, only english

Comment: Check your system locale(s). The locale probably does not exist in the operating system. Search for "linux add locale (distro)"